# When to use JsonResult over ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, return-value

I've been unable to find a concrete answer regarding this question. I've viewed posts and subsequent posts from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250941/actionresult-vs-jsonresult) question and elsewhere but all I've really come out of reading is that JsonResult has a hardcoded content type and there really isn't any performance gains.

If both results can return Json why would you **need** to use JsonResult over ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult()
{
    return Json(foo)
}

public JsonResult()
{
    return Json(bar)
}
```

Can anyone explain a scenario where ActionResult simply can't get the job done and JsonResult **must** be used. If not, why does JsonResult exist in the first place.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> When to use `JsonResult` over `ActionResult`

**I usually return concrete results (e.g. `JsonResult`, `ViewResult`) and there are my pros:**

- **Controller's interface gives more information about it's behavior.** It is easier to work with partial or shared views when you specify `PartialViewResult` and `ViewResult` as result type precisely.
- **It is easier to test** since [it is not needed to cast result to concrete types in your unit tests](http://bengtbe.com/blog/2009/07/01/use-specific-return-types-in-your-asp-net-mvc-action-methods/).

There are some links where people support this approach:

- [What's the difference between ActionResult and ViewResult for action method?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1448398.aspx)
- [Must ASP.NET MVC Controller Methods Return ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021568/must-asp-net-mvc-controller-methods-return-actionresult)
- [ViewResult vs ActionResult](http://forums.asp.net/t/1423519.aspx?ViewResult%20vs%20ActionResult)

There is a quote from [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043):

> Note Notice that that the return type for the action method in the
>   listing is `ViewResult`. The method would compile and work just as well
>   if we had specified the more general `ActionResult` type. In fact, some
>   MVC programmers will define the result of every action method as
>   `ActionResult`, even when they know it will always return a more
>   specific type. We have been particularly diligent in this practice in
>   the examples that follow to make it clear how you can use each result
>   type, but we tend to be more relaxed in real projects.

**I would use `ActionResult` over concrete one only if an action should return different types of results.** But it is not that common situation.

I'd like also to add that `ActionResult` is an abstract class so you cannot simply create an instance of this type and return it. `JsonResult` is concrete so you can create its instance and return from an action method. [There are many other types that derived from `ActionResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743782/902734) and basically all of them are [used to override `ExecuteResult` method](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Types-of-ASPNET-MVC-3-Action-Results).

```
public abstract class ActionResult
{
    public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
}
```

This method is invoked by `ControllerActionInvoker` and implements logic writing data to `response` object.

**`ControllerActionInvoker`** does not know about concrete results so that it **can handle any result that is derived from `ActionResult` and implements `ExecuteResult`**.

In both cases you return an instance of `JsonResult` type in your example and `Json(model)` it is simply a Factory Method that creates an instance of `JsonResult`.

There is another **SO question [Is it better to have a method's datatype be as specific as possible or more general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689530/is-it-better-to-have-a-methods-datatype-be-as-specific-as-possible-or-more-gene) where best practices for method parameters and return values are discussed**.

**The general idea** is **providing abstract types as parameters** so that your method can handle wider range of parameter;  **returning concrete enough types** so that your clients do not need to cast or convert them.

Answer (score 4):

You may have noticed that the names of all the common return types in an MVC controller end with "result", and more often than not, most actions return an ActionResult. If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx#inheritanceContinued), you can see that several, more specalized result types, inherit from the abstract class ActionResult. Because of this, you can now return an ActionResult in all of your actions, and even return different types. Example:

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    var result = _repository.Find(id);
    if(result == null)
        return HttpNotFound(); //HttpNotFoundResult, which inherits from HttpStatusCodeResult
    return View(result); //ViewResult
}
```

All of this makes it easier to return different content, based on the request. So why would you use JsonResult over ActionResult? Perhaps so there are no misunderstandings, and you indeed *only* can return JSON, perhaps for readability, or some other personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

It's just adhering simple **Polymorphism** principle.

By defining the method signature as returning an abstract `ActionResult` which is the base type for `JsonResult`, `ViewResult`, `ContentResult` (and others) you're given the ability to return any of the above types by letting the **implementation** of the action decide which `ActionResult` to return.

For example:

```
public ActionResult GetData(int id)
{
     var data = .... // some data

     if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("json"))
          return Json(data);
     else
          return View(data);
}
```

It is actually a common practice in OOP to define the returned type of the method as abstract as possible. You can find it in .NET BCL as well, the `IEnumerable<>` usage in Linq for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>
                       (
                       this IEnumerable<T> source,
                       Func<T, bool> predicate
                       );
```

The `Where()` method is declared as returning `IEnumerable<T>` so that you can call the method on any type that is implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, be it an `Array`, `List`, `HashSet` or `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

**Actually there is no reasons to use `JsonResult` as return type of Action methods.
In this case it is better to use abstract class `ActionResult` to follow polymorphic principles.**

By calling `return Json(value)`  you are actually calling helper method of Controller class which looks like:

```
protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
    };
}
```

As we can see - `Json` helper method it instantiate `JsonResult` anyway.